# How to minimize the sum of Frobenius norm and Nuclear norm

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, gradient-descent, convex, non-convex

I have to minimize an objective function of the the form :

> $||X_{s} - Y_{s}D_{s}||_{F}^{2} + ||D_{s}||_{F}^{2} + ||D_{s}||_{*}^{2}$

where $||.||_{F}$ denotes the Frobenius norm and $||.||_{*}$ denotes the nuclear norm given by

$||D_{s}||_{*}^{2} = tr((D_{s}^{T}D_{s})^{\frac{1}{2}})$

$X_{s}$ and $Y_{s}$ are data matrices and an optimal value of $D_{s}$ needs to be found out.

Is there a closed form solution to above optimization problem ?

If not, then which solver to use in order to minimize the above objective function ?

Till now I have tried to use ECOS and SCS solvers available with CVXPY library but both of them fall apart after some time (due to memory/processing constraints etc.).

Any better course of action ?

Comment: what are the dimensions of matrices?

Comment: Xs = (100,4086); Ys = (100,300) and Ds = (300,4086) @Aksakal

Comment: I don't think the general closed form solution exists.Nuclear norm is generally non differentiable