# Minimizing a squared error loss with nuclear norm constraint

Tags: machine-learning, python, optimization

I have to minimize an objective function of the the form :

> $||X_{s} - Y_{s}D_{s}||_{F}^{2} + (||D_{s}||_{*}^{2} - 1)$

where $||\cdot||_{F}$ denotes the Frobenius norm and $||\cdot||_{*}$ denotes the nuclear norm.

In the above equation, $X_{s}$ and $Y_{s}$ are data matrices and an optimal value of $D_{s}$ needs to be found out so that it not only has a low value for the nuclear norm but also is able to reconstruct $X_{s}$ given $Y_{s}$.

From the literature available for the nuclear norm, I don't think there is a closed form solution for the above optimization problem ? Also, I am not trying interior point methods since, in the literature, they are reported to have given sub-optimal results.

I was trying to optimize the above function using CVXPY library in Python but unfortunately the code used to collapse  in the middle citing segmentation error.

A similar question was posted by me on [How to minimize the sum of Frobenius norm and Nuclear norm](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/449516/how-to-minimize-the-sum-of-frobenius-norm-and-nuclear-norm)

Could you please help me with some alternate way (preferably using any relevant Python based library) to get the optimal solution for the above problem ?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly where your objective function is coming from, but a couple of things seem strange. (1) Is $\| D_s \|_*^2 - 1$ originally coming from a constraint that $\| D_s \|^2 = 1$ that's been relaxed? In this case you probably want to put a parameter $\lambda > 0$ in to weight the relative importance of satisfying the constraint with the other term, like $\| X - Y D\|_F^2 + \lambda (\| D \|_*^2 - 1)$. (2) Why is the nuclear norm squared? The Frobenius norm being squared makes sense for analytic tractability, but the nuclear norm is analogous to the $\ell_1$ norm.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean $(\|D\|_* - 1)^2$?

Comment: @ericperkerson you are right. what next ?

Comment: @Upendra01 Next, you edit your question to show that you respect the readers' time.

Answer (score 0):

The [proximal forward-backward splitting algorithm](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5697/4187b4d9a8757f4d8a6fd6facc8b4ad08240.pdf) of Combettes and Wajs might be what you want here.  [PyUNLocBoX: Optimization by Proximal Splitting](https://pyunlocbox.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is a  Python package for it (Disclaimer: I have only ever written my own code for this algorithm, so I have never used this package), and documentation on the forward-backward algorithm for the package is [here](https://pyunlocbox.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/compressed_sensing_forward_backward.html?highlight=forward%20backward). You will probably have to adapt their function slightly, as it is written for vector variables, not matrix variables.

The proximal forward-backward splitting algorithm is an iterative algorithm for finding the minimum of a function $h(x) = f(x) + g(x)$, where both $f$ and $g$ are proper convex functions that are lower-semicontinuous, and where $f$ has an $L$-Lipschitz continuous gradient. The function $g$ does not have to be differentiable, however. So you could write $f(D) = \| X - YD \|_F^2$ and $g(D) = \|D\|_*^2$ (In your objective function, the $-1$ is unnecessary, as it does not affect the argmin. That's one reason why I think you might have meant to say $(\|D\|_* - 1)^2$.

The updates are of the form
$$
    x_{k + 1} = [\text{prox}_{\eta g} \circ (\text{id} - \gamma \nabla f)](x_k)
$$
where $\text{prox}_{\eta g}$ is the proximal operator associated with the function $\eta g$ for some parameter $\eta > 0$, and where $0 < \gamma < \frac{2}{L}$. In effect, the iterative step is really two different iterative steps, one which takes a gradient descent step to try to reduce the differentiable piece $f(x)$, and then a proximal-point (kind of like gradient descent for non-differentiable functions) step which to try to reduce the non-differentiable piece $g(x)$. Here, $\gamma$ is the step size for the first part of the update step, and $\eta$ is the step size for the second part of the update step.

The proximal operator associated with a function $g \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined as
$$
\text{prox}_{\eta g} (x) = \text{argmin}_{w \in \mathbb{R}^n} \left( g(w) + \frac{1}{2 \eta} \| w - x \|_2^2 \right)
$$
and you can compute this operator for the nuclear norm, the proximal operator associated to the function $\eta \| \cdot \|_* \colon \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \to \mathbb{R}$ is given by the soft-thresholding operator with parameter $\eta$ applied to the singular values of the argument, i.e.,
$$
\text{prox}_{\eta \| \cdot \|_*} (D) = U \mathcal{S}_\eta (\sigma (D)) V^{\text{T}}
$$
where $\mathcal{S}_\eta$ is the soft-thresholding operator with parameter $\eta$ and svd$ (D) = U \sigma(D) V^{\text{T}}$ is the singular value decomposition of $W$. (This is the part you might have to adapt.)